# PyQt Video doesnt load?

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5

Im trying to play a Video with PyQt. It plays the sound but not the Video, and i couldnt manage to find the mistake. Here is the part of the code where the MediaPlayer is created:

```
self.playlist = QMediaPlaylist()
        self.playlist.addMedia(QMediaContent(QUrl.fromLocalFile('moskaushort.mp4')))
        self.playlist.addMedia(QMediaContent(QUrl.fromLocalFile('Crabrave.mp4')))
        self.playlist.setCurrentIndex(1)
        self.player = QMediaPlayer(self.centralwidget, QMediaPlayer.VideoSurface)
        self.player.setPlaylist(self.playlist)
        self.VideoPlayer = QVideoWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.VideoPlayer.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 190, 371, 231))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setStyleStrategy(QtGui.QFont.PreferDefault)
        self.VideoPlayer.setFont(font)
        self.VideoPlayer.setAccessibleName("")
        self.VideoPlayer.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        self.VideoPlayer.setObjectName("VideoPlayer")
        self.player.setVideoOutput(self.VideoPlayer)
        self.player.stateChanged.connect(self.mediaStateChanged)
        self.player.error.connect(self.handleError)
```

If you need more code i´ll post it.

Comment: Please post a *minimal* working example, of what your problem is

Comment: I rewrote it now, i hope its fine like that ^^

Answer (score 0):

Okay, just found out that im somewhat stupid and it was the most obvious mistake... I just installed the K-Lite Codec pack and it works ^^

Answer (score 0):

If you are on windows, this worked for me for loading mp4 files:

os.environ['QT_MULTIMEDIA_PREFERRED_PLUGINS'] = 'windowsmediafoundation'

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).